# Git Status not being displayed

Tags: php, git

The following code creates shell.sh, gitstatus.txt but gitstatus.txt is empty. If i execute the commented part then dir is created. Why the values are not getting into gitstatus.txt file?Any clue?

```
<?php


$command = "echo '#!/bin/sh'>shell.sh";
exec($command);
$cmnd = "echo 'git status >gitstatus.txt'>>shell.sh";


//$cmnd = "echo 'mkdir rr1'>>shell.sh";

exec($cmnd);

$cmd1 = "sh shell.sh";
exec($cmd1);
?>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to accieve. You should a) express clearly your goals and b) cleanup your code. Why do you want to create a shell script just to run it afterwards? why not execute the commands directly from php?

Comment: While trying to run directly, I found that that these commands run directly on local host but not on remote server.

Comment: @rr You should try to explain a bit better what you want to do. Do you want just to write the output of `git status` into a file? Do you want to do that on 'remote server'?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info further up. However: you really expect to get any answer here when you don't even mention things like 'remote' and 'server' in the question? How should anyone guess your intent?

Comment: how in the world is this code meant to run on the remote server any more than executing them directly from php? you're here creating a shell script that is making git commands that is creating a text file. that doesn't seem to make any kind of sense at all.

Comment: @grosshat  Yes i want to run git status command on remote server and get the output on webpage. If gitstatus.txt file is created then i can read from there and display the contents on webpage. That's my line of thinking.But got struck in filling gitstatus.txt!!!

Comment: @rr but that does not explain why you don't just do `exec('git status..'`

Comment: @eis exec(git status) is not working on remote server. Php script is creating files with username "nonpriv".So it is not able to run shell script made by any other user. So I tried to let PHP make the shell script and run it(as there would be no user issue).That worked fine till creating and executing shell script but does not functions properly because as i told gitstatus.txt is created but not filled with git status. I found that if commands like mkdir is given in shell, then they are executed but commands like git status, ls , etc which give some output are not getting executed.